# Need help declaring methods

Tags: java

Java program that first asks the user for a list of dates, and then prints the earliest date, the latest date, and the average year of the dates, I can't get it to compile to save my life, having trouble declaring methods in other methods, I am very new to programming.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Proj6 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a list of dates: ");
    String list = s.nextLine();

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(list, ", ");
    String[] dates = new String[st.countTokens()];

    for (int i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        dates[i] = st.nextToken();
    }


    Proj6.printEarliest(dates);
    Proj6.printLatest(dates);
    Proj6.printAvgYear(dates);
}

/**
 * getMonth returns the month in a date
 * of the form month/day/year
 *
 * @param date - A date of the form month/day/year
 * @return The month of the given date
 */
public static int getMonth(String date) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(date, "/");
    return Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
}

/**


 * getDay returns the day in a date
 * of the form month/day/year
 *
 * @param date - A date of the form month/day/year
 * @return The day of the given date
 */
public static int getDay(String date) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(date, "/");
    st.nextToken();
    return Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
}


/**
 * getYear returns the year in a date
 * of the form month/day/year
 *
 * @param date - A date of the form month/day/year
 * @return The year of the given date
 */
public static int getYear(String date) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(date, "/");
    st.nextToken();
    st.nextToken();
    return Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
}

/**
 * printEarliest prints the date that comes chronologically
 * first from the dates array
 *
 * @param dates - An array of dates, all of the form month/day/year
 */
public static void printEarliest(String[] dates) {

    int i = 0;
    Proj6.getYear(dates);
    Proj6.getMonth(dates);
    Proj6.getDay(dates);
    for (i= 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        if(getYear.dates [i]<=getYear.dates[i])

        st.nextToken();
    }
        System.out.println("Earliest date:" + dates[i]);
    }







/**
 * printLatest prints the date that comes chronologically
 * last from the dates array
 *
 * @param dates - An array of dates, all of the form month/day/year
 */
public static void printLatest(String[] dates) {


}

/**
 * printAvgYear prints the average year among all the dates in
 * the dates array
 *
 * @param dates - An array of dates, all of the form month/day/year
 */
public static void printAvgYear(String[] dates) {
    proj6.getYear();
   int sum = 0;
   int avg = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        sum = getYear + sum;
        dates[i] = st.nextToken();
}
avg = sum/dates.length;
System.out.println("Average:" + avg);
```

}
}

Comment: please post code and any errors printing to the console

Comment: you cant "declare" method inside other methods in java. post what youve got so far and we help you

Comment: you can probably do with just one method aside from the main method that reads user inputs. The other method could take a list of dates, then iterate to find the earliest, latest and average (like you said). what exactly is the query?

Comment: Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html). Voting to close.

Comment: just added what I have so far

Comment: ok, so, what are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: what is wrong with my code so far?

Comment: @KyleHammel What **is** wrong with your code so far? It doesn't compile? Okay. What errors are generated by the compiler? That should point you (and us) in the direction of what's actually wrong. Here's a quick one from `printAvgYear()`: `proj6.getYear()`. Static methods are called using the class name, which is case-sensitive, i.e. it should be called as `Proj6.getYear()`

Comment: it says getYear cannot be applied to Proj6 in printEarliest

Comment: @Kyle, please stop posting the same comments that provide little or no additional information. Edit your question to explain what it is you're trying to accomplish, and to provide the error messages you're getting when you try to compile. It's pointless to expect people to play 20 questions trying to pry information out of you to use to help you. It's also much faster for you to get help. :)

Comment: sorry like I said I am very new to this, however I figured out my previous problem but now I am trying to compare the years, months, and days to find the lowest and highest date in two different methods, but it is just printing out the first date I input, how do I get it to print out the correct date?

Comment: i would iterate over the array and extract min, max and avg in a single loop. but you could convert the array into a arraylist and do a Collections.sort giving a comparator, assuming its a really small set of data and you won't mind sorting. you can use SimpledateFormat to get date from string and date has before() and after() methods for comparison. please post your updated code if you are unable to figure out and need specific pointers.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you don't declare methods inside of other methods (like you can in javascript).

You have a class that contains all your methods. They can call each other.

When you say "asks" do you mean you need the program that's running in the terminal to ask a question and then wait for input and then act when the user inputs something?

If that's the case, if you wanted to ask the user for their username, for example, you would do this:

```
Console console = System.console();
String username = console.readLine("User Name? ");
```

This would hang out waiting for the `[enter]` key and collect whatever was in the keyboard buffer into your username String... you could then proceed with acting on it.

And welcome to Stack.  Please don't forget to mark answers as correct when your questions have been answered, and to mark up the answers that you feel are most helpful.

Comment: In light of your posted code, my answer isn't really relevant to your question.  I'll delete it if you don't find it useful.